# trying to send data using POST from android to sql

Tags: php, android

I am trying to POST data from my android to my sql server

This is in my android application

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName",value));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

This is my php

```
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];

$sql = "SELECT firstName FROM `colleague` WHERE `lastName` 
   LIKE '%$firstName%' LIMIT 0, 5 ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) $output[] = $row['firstName'];

echo implode("<br/>",$output);
print(json_encode($output));
```

But this now selects the first five rows .. it does not receive anything in $firstName = $_POST["firstName"]; ??

php Notice

```
Undefined index: firstName in C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

http declaration

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1/Search.php");
```

Comment: I feel the need to point out that you're generating raw SQL and failing to escape the (user supplied) firstName input. This is a vector for SQL injection.

Comment: Can you give the code you use to define `httppost`?

Comment: I would suggest you use a simple REST wrapper around your server code. Its much more elegant and safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];` try single quotations. do you have spaces in the value for $firstName? if it is encoded, do decoding in php. Example if you have `Your(space)Name` then encoded form will be `Your+Name`, if you dont decode it the query has encoded value for `$firstName`. Use `urldecode($_POST['firstName'])` to decode the encoded url content

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem at all. He already said that the POST dictionary has no index for firstName, so there's nothing to decode. And quote type doesn't matter.

Comment: If he is using BasicNameValuePair("firstName",value) maybe he has to try $_REQUEST['firstName'].. Don't you think the same?